# Handle multiple user at the same time with TelegramLongPollingBot and thread

Tags: java, telegram-bot

I'm building my first telegram bot. It send one message every 5 seconds to the user.

While it sends it to one user it cannot receive update from other chat.

```
public void foo(msg, Update update){
    msg.setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId());
    for (int i = 1; i < links.size(); i++){
        msg.setText(links.get(i));
        execute(msg);
    }
    Thread.sleep(wait * 1000);
}
```

How can I use Thread? I've tried creating multiple thread here

```
public static void bot(){

    ApiContextInitializer.init();
    TelegramBotsApi  telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
    try {
        telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new myBot());
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But he tries to create multiple bots and fails. Same if this is the runnable function:

How can I do it? I'm Stuck. I cannot create this function in different thread

```
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

    leggi(new SendMessage(), update.getMessage().getText(),  update);

    //.setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId())


public void  leggi(SendMessage msg, String command, Update update){ 
    if(command.equals("test") {
        foo( msg, update);
    }
```

Here the full code...  https://github.com/siamoInPochi/Ilsottomarinobot/tree/prova/src/main/java/Ilsottomarinobot

Answer (score 0):

If you spawn a thread for every bot user who wants to receive messages, you will quickly be out of computer's resources in case of high number of users. So I think threads is not a good idea for your task.

In my mind more natural approach is the following:

- Find a library with an HTTP server.
- Switch from `GetUpdates` to webhooks.
- Schedule `send-message-to-user-every-5-seconds` tasks to server's event loop.
- Send messages every 5 seconds asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with this library https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.pengrad</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-telegram-bot-api</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

1. Subscribe to new updates via `bot.setUpdatesListener`
2. Send messages via `bot.execute(new SendMessage(chatId, link), callback)`

Full working example:

```java
static String[] links = {"1", "2", "3"};

static Callback emptyCallback = new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(BaseRequest request, BaseResponse response) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(BaseRequest request, IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
};

static void foo(TelegramBot bot, Update update) {
    Message message = update.message();
    if (message == null) return;

    Long chatId = message.chat().id();
    for (String link : links) {
        bot.execute(new SendMessage(chatId, link), emptyCallback);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TelegramBot bot = new TelegramBot(TOKEN);

    bot.setUpdatesListener(updates -> {
        for (Update update : updates) {
            foo(bot, update);
        }
        return UpdatesListener.CONFIRMED_UPDATES_ALL;
    });
}
```